# php login username and password with filters

Tags: php, validation, authentication, filter

I have been reading in almost everywhere that we should not use our own custom login and password validations ( like regex etc.) but instead use the filter_var and filter_input built in functions provided by PHP 5 and above. However even after searching for more than an hour for with different search strings, I have not found even a single example that shows how we may validate for a username/login and password in a login form. Can someone be kind enough to provide a strong secure validations for username and login.

Additionally I would also like to clarify if the username and login fields in a Login form be manipulated in any manner to pose a security threat? I mean can a hacker craft a username/login or password in such a manner as to pose an injection or any other threat?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

the filter functions in php5+ simplify the way you validate user input datas. For example:

if you have a registration form with an email and password field, you can check if the email is valid with the following code:

```
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    // Everything okay
} else // Email is malformatted
```

There are no filters for check the qualitiy of passwords. You can find an overview of the available filter here: http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php.

There are also filters for sanitize userinputs, for example: If you want to sanitize an email address you can use the following code:

```
$sanitized_email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
```

you may have a look here for all available sanitization filters and what they are exactly doing here: http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. See that's the point I have come across all these examples for validating emails, URI's, IP addresses even integers, but I could not find a single example of username and password. I would be glad if someone can provide an example for these two specific cases which I think would also serve as a tutorial for Login validation using PHP filters. Thanks!

Comment: Well that depends pretty much on what u want to do. What are the typicall filter rules for usernames? Thats pretty much your own decision! It simply does not exist a default behaviour for usernames and passwords, therefore the filter library does not have filters for usernames and passwords. Define your standard by yourselfe. Thats why i pointed out the email example because many modern websites are using email addresses as usernames.

Comment: If you dont want to use emails as usernames you only want to sanitize the user input so that they cant save HTML and stuff in your database => Use FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS on username. Maybe you dont want that usernames can be longer then 255 characters, so check that, but like I said, that depends on ur needs. For passwords I only would check a min length, just use strlen and hash it with crypt before you save it to the database. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code to filter username

```
$username= filter_input(INPUT_POST,'username',FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
```

1. First parameter form method get/post
2. second parameter input name ex:`<input type="text" name="username">`
3. third parameter filter type you can read more about it http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php